# Basics of searching for data considering typos and partial results

Tags: database, algorithm, search, firebird

I have a large database (firebird) containing address information for every address on my country (Brazil).
This will be used to locate addresses inputed by users.

My main concern is how to implement a search engine capable of resolving typos, partial results, or results that are similar to the search query.

I'm pretty clueless as to where I would begin to implement this kind of capability. 
What are the terminologies I should be looking for?
Is there any kind of service on the internet that would provide these capabilities, given that I provide the data?

Comment: This is called address standardization.  There are third-party vendors that can handle this in many countries, presumably Brazil as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's not actually a problem specific to addresses per say, but to data querying.
For example, if the user inputs "plista", I want the system to be able to guess he meant "paulista"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need Free text search capability

All the info is here [Full Text Search with Firebird and Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952830/full-text-search-with-firebird-and-delphi)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to know [Wildcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) and [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and [Fuzzy Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). You can google for a lot of information. You may also need to know [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Those above are very complicated algorithms. But there are libraries which you can use for different languages like [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).